# Getting percentage of total in SQL with two joins

Tags: mysql, sql, relational-database

So I'm trying to do something that I think should be fairly simple with SQL. But I'm having a hard time figuring it out. Here is the format of my data:

One table with user information, let's call it User:

```
ID name_user   Drive_Type
1   Tim        Stick shift
2   Jim        Automatic
3   Bob        Automatic
4   Lisa       Stick shift
```

Then I have one table used for the join, let's call it Join_bridge:

```
user_ID  car_has_ID
1        12
2        13
3        14
4        14
```

And one table with car information, let's call it Car:

```
car_ID  name  
12      Honda   
13      Toyota   
14      Ford
```

Then what I want is something that looks like this with the total number of Ford's that are stick shift and the percentage

```
name   Total percentage
 Ford   1    25%
```

I have tried the following, which gets the total right, but not the percentage:

```
select Drive_Type, 
        name, 
        count(Drive_Type) as Total, 
        (count(Drive_Type) / (select count(*) 
            from User
            join Join_bridge
            on User.ID = user_ID
            join Car
            on Car.car_ID = Join_bridge.car_has_ID 
        ) * 100.0 as Percent
    from User
            join Join_bridge
            on User.ID = Join_bridge.user_ID
            join Car
            on Car.car_ID = Join_bridge.car_has_ID  
    where name = 'Ford' and Drive_Type = "Automatic"
;
```

What am I missing? Thanks.

Comment: SO really there is only one `14      Ford` in the `Cars` table right.

Comment: correct, its been edited to reflect that

Comment: Based on your data sample it's returning the correct percentage that you're looking for so I don't see anything wrong with the query except for the additional parenthesis before the percentage's `count( ..` syntax. And you said _"...  of Ford's that are stick shift"_ but your query is `where name = 'Ford' and Drive_Type = "Automatic"`. Can you post the result you're getting?

Answer (score 0):

See [this](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/ce021f/13/0) SQL Fiddle with the query - the trick is to SUM over CASE that returns 1 for rows you look for and 0 for the rest in order to calculate "Total" at the same time you can also count all rows to calculate percentage.

Here's the SQL query:

```
SELECT
  'Ford' name,
  SUM(a.ford_with_stack_flag) Total,
  100.0 * SUM(a.ford_with_stack_flag) / COUNT(*) percentage
FROM (
  SELECT
      Car.name,
      (CASE WHEN User.Drive_Type = 'Stick Shift' and Car.name = 'Ford' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) ford_with_stack_flag
  FROM User
  JOIN Join_bridge on User.ID = Join_bridge.user_ID
  JOIN Car ON Car.car_ID = Join_bridge.car_has_ID
) a
```

Comment: Edited with the SQL query. What's wrong with link only answer?

Comment: links go down occasionally and can't be used anymore, further the idea is that some with the same problem has to find you, didn't you make the tour or read the help pages at all?

Comment: SQL fiddle isn't a help page, it's an interactive shell for running SQL queries and see the results which I and others find more helpful than just presenting the written SQL query that can't execute

Comment: What @nbk is saying is the stack overflow's help page. As it stated _"Links to external resources are encouraged, but please add context around the link so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there. **Always quote the most relevant part of an important link, in case the external resource is unreachable or goes permanently offline.**"_ Refer to [how to answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)

Answer (score 0):

Compute percent and join to Car. Window functions are supported in MySql 8.0

```
select c.car_ID, c.name, p.cnt, p.Percent
from car c
join (
    select car_has_ID, u.Drive_Type, 
        count(*) cnt, 
        count(*) / count(count(*)) over() Percent
    from Join_bridge b
    join user u on u.ID = b.user_ID
    group by b.car_has_ID, u.Drive_Type
   ) p on p.car_has_ID = c.car_ID
where c.name = 'Ford' and p.Drive_Type='Stick shift';
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=f6dcc04feccbb7566b02833657e53ff9)